# Limit based Conditional Formatting in Excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

I am looking for a solution in excel with formula for conditional formatting.

If in `Column A` value is `0.550 ± 0.030` and then I enter a value in next `Column B`. If entered value is within that limit then it should highlight in one white color and if out off limit it should highlight in red color.

Comment: Can you explain more it is not clear maybe a screenshot and more description?

Comment: What have you tried? Also, is the tolerance the same for all numbers? Apart from that, conditional formatting will probably do what you need, but further info will confirm that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming *one column* is A, select B:B and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=OR(B1>LEFT(A1,FIND(" ±",A1))+MID(A1,FIND("±",A1)+2,25),B1<LEFT(A1,FIND(" ±",A1))-MID(A1,FIND("±",A1)+2,25))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select red fill, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.